# Programmatically creating an article in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin that is able to update a case in CRM, but I now want it to create a new knowledge base article, as I don't believe it is possible to automate this using a workflow. The plugin is triggered by a workflow that is executed when a case is resolved.

Here is what I have so far but it does not work:

```
Entity article = new Entity("kbarticle");
article["title"] = articleTitle;
article["subject"] = articleSubject;

service.Create(article);

Guid articleGUID = service.Create(article);

ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "description" });

article = service.Retrieve(article.LogicalName, articleGUID, attributes);

article["description"] = articleDescription;

service.Update(article);
```

Comment: What doesnt work in particular?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly as CRM doesn't provide any debug information. All I can say is that a new article isn't created and the workflow doesn't complete, sorry!

Comment: Is the workflow stuck in a waiting state? If so then its probably errored, check the Crm logs on the workflow record itself.

Comment: Yes its just stuck in a waiting state, and there is an error next to the plugin job on the workflow record

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: It's just an error symbol - not much help unfortunately

Comment: There will be a proper error for this. You need to give us the trace. I've updated my answer with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the answers, they all helped to send me in the right direction towards a solution. The main issue was that I needed to use entity references for the subjectid and template:

```
Entity kbarticle = new Entity("kbarticle");

kbarticle["title"] = title;
kbarticle["subjectid"] = new EntityReference(subject_LogicalName, subject_Guid);
kbarticle["kbarticletemplateid"] = new EntityReference(template_LogicalName, template_Guid);

service.Create(kbarticle);
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things...

### Invalid attribute

```cs
article["subject"] = articleSubject;
```

`subject` is not a valid attribute on the `kbarticle` entity. `subjectid` *is* but will need to be a `Lookup` to a valid subject record. I can't tell from your snippet if it is or not.

### Missing attribute

According to the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309345.aspx), you also need to specify a KB template:

> When you create a knowledge base article, you have to associate it with a knowledge base template and a subject...

[snip]

> To associate an article with a template, use the KbArticle.
>   KbArticleTemplateId attribute. To place an article in a specific
>   category by specifying a subject, use the KbArticle.SubjectId
>   attribute.

### Redundant code

Also, probably not the source of your error, but your code tries to create the article twice. Your first line of code here is redundant:

```
service.Create(article);

Guid articleGUID = service.Create(article);
```

Beyond that, we really do need to know the error that is raised by your code (though I suspect it will be my first point).

Comment: Thanks for this, yes you were right, it's subjectid and not subject. And as it's a lookup I needed to use entity references as described in my answer. I would vote up but I don't have enough rep yet! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309345.aspx) article, its not a code example but it describes the steps to create an article.

Edit:

You need to provide us with more debugging information. Either;

- Enable Tracing as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490) or use this handy [tool](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/new-tool-crmdiagtool-2011.html). Reproduce the problem and post the log.
- Post the error from the workflow itself, as shown [here](http://www.avanadeblog.com/.a/6a0120a757f751970b0133f53f5d36970b-800wi).
- Attach the debugger and find out whats going on that way.

You would probably find it easier to develop the article creation code against unit tests in Visual Studio, then you can just hook it up to a workflow activity later.

Comment: thanks for your help. The article was useful and helped me get to my answer in the end (would have been nice if MS supplied some example code for it). CRM plugins are a bit of a nightmare to debug so thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

It should look like

```
        KbArticle a = new KbArticle();
        a.Title = articleTitle;
        a.SubjectId = new Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference(Subject.EntityLogicalName, subjectGuid);
        service.Create(a);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are going to be more steps after this as described in the MSDN article I linked.